# How to test deleting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am working in Rails and setting up automated testing. I am getting a " No route matches [DELETE] '/adjusters/1/edit' " when I test my delete method. I know the delete method works because I have gone to the website and tested it myself. Here is the code I am using to test my delete. Does anyone see a reason why my test would not pass?

```
  # creating an instance variable to test with
  def setup
    @adjuster = Adjuster.create(adjuster_name: "TestLastName", address_1: "4511 W 200 S", id: 1)
  end

  # Testing going to an already created adjuster and deleting them
  test "get edit adjuster form and delete adjuster" do
    delete edit_adjuster_path(@adjuster)
    follow_redirect!
    assert_nil(@adjuster)
  end
```

I raked the routes from the console to ensure the route existed too.

```
DELETE /adjusters/:id(.:format)      adjusters#destroy
```

I have successfully used get edit_adjuster_path(@adjuster) to update their information.

Comment: add `assert_equal 42, edit_adjuster_path(@adjuster)` to the top of your test and run it, to see what `edit_adjuster_path(@adjuster)` is returning. It says "edit" not "destroy" in it. Should it be `adjusters_destroy_path`?

Comment: it returned "/adjusters/1/edit", which is the page where my delete button is at.  I get an undefined method for adjuster_destroy_path.

Comment: You are telling the test to hit your site with a HTTP DELETE verb, so you don't need the "edit" version of the page (unless you have one action in your controller to do two things). Did you try `adjuster_destroy_path`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo error. Sorry. I will try switching to the main index page and using delete. I assumed I had to use the edit path since that was where my delete button was at.

Comment: When I try deleting from the index page I receive a failure(not error) message that the instance variable is still not nil.

Comment: The variable `@adjuster` is in the tests, not the production code. If the production code assigns `@adjuster = nil`, check it with `assert_nil assigns(:adjuster)`. But there are better ways to test a record got deleted...

Comment: I changed my last line to assert_nil assigns(:adjuster) and the test passed. So I'll take it for a Friday afternoon solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fixes were:

A> use the correct path to the DELETE action; `adjuster_destroy_path(@adjuster)`, and

B> assert that the controller's instance variable got unset correctly, with `assert_nil assigns(:adjuster)`.